# I properly installed PIL but still get the No Module Error

Tags: path, terminal, homebrew, python-imaging-library

```
Grizz-MacBook-Pro:~ Grizz$ cd /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Grizz-MacBook-Pro:site-packages Grizz$ ls
PIL             pip-6.0.8-py2.7.egg
Pillow-2.7.0-py2.7.egg-info setuptools-12.0.5-py2.7.egg
PyQt4               setuptools.pth
easy-install.pth        sip.so
hgext               sipconfig.py
homebrew-pillow-nose.pth    sipdistutils.py
mercurial           sitecustomize.py
mercurial-3.3-py2.7.egg-info    sitecustomize.pyc
```

It looks like PIL is installed in the correct PATH and when I go to use it in Sublime I get the:

```
'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Grizz/Documents/Python Files/Weather APP/WeatherApp.py",     line 4, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ImportError: No module named PIL
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/Users/Grizz/Documents/Python Files/Weather     APP/WeatherApp.py"]
[dir: /Users/Grizz/Documents/Python Files/Weather APP]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

I'm hoping to figure out either how to change the PIL path to ammend it to my system python path so I can run it in my interpreter or to uninstal and redownload PIL the correct way.

I'm new to Mac OS and have been able to troubleshoot most everything until now. I'm guessing it's because I'm running off my sys Python 2.7 and not a brew installeld 2.7... can someone walk me through this?

Comment: I found a work around that allows me to add photos using Python 2.7 where I don't need PIL. Basically, I was trying to upload PNG files and not GIF files. GIF files work for me - if anyone can clarify why just for frame of reference that'd be awesome. Otherwise, I can insert an image so I'm happy!

Comment: Can you share `brew doctor` and `brew config`?